# coercing a paramter into an integer in Body Mapping Template, AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I've been using a bit of arithmetic in the Body Mapping Template in Integration Request:

```
#set($now = $context.requestTimeEpoch/1000)
#set($soon = $now + 600)
{
    "TableName": "events",
.... [ here get events between $now and $soon]
}
```

Recently I came to need to pass an offset through a parameter:

```
#set($now = $context.requestTimeEpoch/1000)
#set($soon = $now + $input.params('offset'))
{
    "TableName": "events",
.... [ here get events between $now and $soon] ....
}
```

It turns out that if `$now`  is `1518939082`, with query paramter `?offset=600` `$soon` will be `1518939082600` - a concatenation. I have tried various ways to force the parameter being recognised as an integer, including:

1. `#set($offset = $Integer.parseInt($input.params('offset')))`
2. `#set($offset = 0 + $input.params('offset'))`
3. `#set($offset = 1 * $input.params('offset'))`

None of them works. I inserted `#set($offset = 0)` before each test so I can tell "nothing happens" from "a nothingness is returned".

1. In the first case, $offset prints an empty string, *not 0*. (This happens to `$Integer.parseInt("1")` too.)
2. In the second case, $offset prints a concatenation of "0" and the string value of "offset".
3. In the third case, $offset prints a 0, as if the entire line doesn't exist.

None of them successfully transformed the parameter to an integer.

Is there a way to use that parameter as an integer?

Comment: Please clarify *"none of them works"*... do they all still behave as strings, or throw errors, or exactly what?  What does something like `$Integer.parseInt($input.params('offset')) + ($context.requestTimeEpoch/1000)` do?

Comment: I added the test results the best I could. The Body Mapping Template in Amazon never throw any error or give any error message in the Integration Test interface, despite the test log is extremely detailed, so we can only observe its behaviour through the change of variable value. Your suggestion, however, gave a strange result of `"$context.requestTimeEpoch/1000"` despite I didn't quote that expression in the source code.